# How to wait for pages with long load time to load in testcafe?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, next.js, e2e-testing, testcafe

From these docs:
https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/actions/navigate.html

It looks like we can only wait 15 seconds for a page to load.

We develop a NextJS application and it's first load takes **40 seconds** because it builds the app on the first load.

I can't seem to make TestCafe not timeout on the initial page load.

I tried

```
fixture('Restaurant List')
  .page('http://localhost:3000/something')
  .beforeEach(async () => {
    await waitForReact(120000);
  });
```

For example with no success.

Answer (score 5):

You can send the first request that initiates the application building process and run your tests only when response will be received.

See a code example below:

```js
const rp             = require('request-promise');
const createTestCafe = require('testcafe');
rp('https://site-url')
    .then(() => {       
         return createTestCafe('localhost', 1337, 1338);
    })   
    .then(testcafe => {
         runner = testcafe.createRunner();

         return runner
             .src('tests');
             .browsers('chrome');
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try --page-load-timeout 40000

More info here:
https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html#--page-load-timeout-ms

Or pause first test
https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/pausing-the-test.html

Comment: **--page-load-timeout <ms>**:
Specifies the time (in milliseconds) passed after the DOMContentLoaded event... (doesnt helps)

Comment: In that case --selector-timeout <ms> and .wait(ms) are only options

Comment: nope. page wont even get to this point. look at the link:  https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/actions/navigate.html